# SQL Azure Migration Wizard with connection error

Tags: sql, azure

I'm trying to migrate SQL server data into Azure when i stumbled upon this program called SQL Azure Migration Wizard. I heard many success stories with it. However when i reached this steps, i'm stuck. I searched the discussion from the wizard and didnt find any resources.

So exactly, what are this username and password are from?

[image]

As what Dennis Burton suggested, I typed my server name and the password i used to create my Azure SQL into the 2 textfield. However when i clicked connect, i received this error. I have already allowed my IP address in Azure SQL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These come from your Windows Azure SQL Database instance.

The User name will look like: username@server

If you log into the portal, go to your database instance and look at the dashboard, you can see you server name. Also, from the dashboard, there is a show connection strings link that will show you everything except the password. You should have the password from when the database was created.

Comment: I know it is a silly question, but... Did you replace SERVER with your server name in the first input box? that particular input box requires yourservername.database.windows.net and not just the server name.

Comment: Yes i did. I replaced the entire server name with the server name provided by windows azure. I also replaced my userID and password accordingly to what is given in the connection strings. However, i still receive the networking error.